# NO_PUBKEY 29D5D019FDA658E8 when doung update 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04

I get the following error when doing an update. How do I fix this ?

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: GPG error: file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 29D5D019FDA658E8
E: The repository 'file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local  InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

As the answers provided by others did not fix the issue, I provide here the answer to my own problem in case others have it also:

1. Go to Nvidia website and do the deb local install. They seem to have updated the keys

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pinsudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.1.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local_12.1.1-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local_12.1.1-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Comment: There's a lot of mess in your `sources.list`. Many are incompatible and others are just invalid. Remove the unofficial sources you added and try again. Adding sources fundamentally changes your system and adding incompatible sources or sources from a different distribution is a fast track to break things. I'd get rid of all of these unofficial sources. Then you should be able to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. If that still doesn't work, you'll want to uninstall all of the software installed from bad sources. You may need to reinstall the OS if things are too badly broken.

Comment: See also: [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629). This specifically discusses PPAs but the information generally applies to any non-official sources. Avoid adding sources unless absolutely necessary. And even then, take great care to make sure that the sources you add are actually compatible with your system and won't break your package management or cause dependency issues with your other software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: i AM STILL A BIT CONFUSED,
W: GPG error: file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 29D5D019FDA658E8
ther is no key for thi. But How do I remove it without destroying my system?

Comment: ```sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 29D5D019FDA658E8
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.XNz4dw8Vm5/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 29D5D019FDA658E8
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data```

Comment: The real anser is
* ```wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin```
* ```sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.1.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local_12.1.1-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb```
* ```sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local_12.1.1-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb```
* ```sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-1-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/```
* ```sudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get -y install cuda```

Comment: The answers provided by Nmath are unfortunately not helpful. In fact they create more confusions as this is a specific error and a general answer is provided that does not fix a specific error. Please, instead see my answer after I investigated the problem for some time now. It looks like nVIDIA fixed the issue and you can follow the updated instructions on the NVIDIA Web SIte . I used the local deb install.